# Oracle XMLTYPE extract root prolog value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xmltype

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
*Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production*
```

I have sample Query with XML like below:

```
with t(xml) as 
(
select xmltype(
'<SSO_XML
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
TimeStamp="2020-08-05T21:57:23Z" 
Target="Production" 
Version="1.0" 
TransactionIdentifier="PLAN_A" 
SequenceNmbr="123456"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PlanCode PlanCodeCode="CHOICE">
        <S_DAYS FARE="10" Start="2020-08-07" End="2020-10-30" Mon="true" Tue="true" Weds="true" Thur="true" Fri="true" Sat="true" Sun="true">
            <STUDENT>
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="1" />
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="2" />
            </STUDENT>
        </S_DAYS>
    </PlanCode>
</SSO_XML>') 
 from dual
 )

select h.PlanCodeCode
,b.Original
,b.code
,b.s_code
 from   t
    cross join
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             '/SSO_XML'
             passing t.xml
             columns PlanCodeCode varchar2(100)  path './PlanCode/@PlanCodeCode',
                     attributes xmltype path './PlanCode'
            ) h
    cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             'PlanCode/S_DAYS/STUDENT/DIVISION'
             passing h.attributes
             columns 
                    ORIGINAL number path  '@ORIGINAL',
                    Code            varchar2(100) path '@Code',
                    S_CODE  number path '@S_CODE'
            ) b;
```

Output:

[image]

I am trying to fetch the values below within the query or a new query:
Is there any way to do that? Any help  / direction appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to complete your first XMLTABLE query (h) in this way:

```
target  varchar2(100) path '/SSO_XML/@Target',
transactionId  varchar2(100) path '/SSO_XML/@TransactionIdentifier'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to include two attributes, which are accessed with a `@` prefix; so your query can be modified to:

```
select h.PlanCodeCode
,h.target
,h.transactionIdentifier
,b.Original
,b.code
,b.s_code
 from   t
    cross join
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             '/SSO_XML'
             passing t.xml
             columns PlanCodeCode varchar2(100)  path './PlanCode/@PlanCodeCode',
                     target varchar2(100) path '@Target',
                     transactionIdentifier varchar2(100) path '@TransactionIdentifier',
                     attributes xmltype path './PlanCode'
            ) h
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46d74ef53f1066671b6f89677eb3d3ed)

In this case you could also do this in a single XMLTable call, which is shorter but possibly harder to read and maintain:

```
select b.PlanCodeCode
,b.target
,b.transactionIdentifier
,b.Original
,b.code
,b.s_code
 from   t
    cross join
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             '/SSO_XML/PlanCode/S_DAYS/STUDENT/DIVISION'
             passing t.xml
             columns PlanCodeCode varchar2(100)  path './../../../@PlanCodeCode',
                     target varchar2(100) path './../../../../@Target',
                     transactionIdentifier varchar2(100) path './../../../../@TransactionIdentifier',
                     ORIGINAL number path  '@ORIGINAL',
                     Code varchar2(100) path '@Code',
                     S_CODE  number path '@S_CODE'
            ) b;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0eb158e6634a619f1105be6e37b3208a)

Comment: Yeah.. I spent hours googling for unnecessary keywords for this. :) my mind didn't go through this .. Thanks Alex. Upvoting yours and acceptingThomas's .. both of your input helped..he is first.