# Oracle XMLTYPE extract node depth level number

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xmltype

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
*Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production*
```

This is an extension ask for another [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122155/oracle-xmltype-extract-root-prolog-value)

I have sample Query with XML like below:

```
with t(xml) as 
(
select xmltype(
'<SSO_XML
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
TimeStamp="2020-08-05T21:57:23Z" 
Target="Production" 
Version="1.0" 
TransactionIdentifier="PLAN_A" 
SequenceNmbr="123456"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PlanCode PlanCodeCode="CHOICE">
        <S_DAYS FARE="10" Start="2020-08-07" End="2020-10-30" Mon="true" Tue="true" Weds="true" Thur="true" Fri="true" Sat="true" Sun="true">
            <STUDENT>
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="1" />
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="2" />
            </STUDENT>
        </S_DAYS>
        <S_DAYS FARE="20" Start="2020-08-07" End="2020-10-30" Mon="true" Tue="true" Weds="true" Thur="true" Fri="true" Sat="true" Sun="true">
            <STUDENT>
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="1" />
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="2" />
            </STUDENT>
        </S_DAYS>
    </PlanCode>
</SSO_XML>') 
 from dual
 )

select h.PlanCodeCode
,b.Original
,b.code
,b.s_code
,node_level
 from   t
    cross join
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             '/SSO_XML'
             passing t.xml
             columns PlanCodeCode varchar2(100)  path './PlanCode/@PlanCodeCode',
                     attributes xmltype path './PlanCode'
            ) h
    cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             'PlanCode/S_DAYS/STUDENT/DIVISION'
             passing h.attributes
             columns 
                    ORIGINAL number path  '@ORIGINAL',
                    Code            varchar2(100) path '@Code',
                    S_CODE  number path '@S_CODE',
                    node_level      for ordinality
            ) b;
```

I am trying to get the node depth / level number.
Here I have 2 S_DAYS nodes. I wanted to print the level number sequentially.

Actual Result:

[image: Actual Result:]

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result:]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR ORDINALITY` returns only a generated row number. So it must be generated on the level you want to count.

```
with t(xml) as 
(
select xmltype(
'<SSO_XML
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
TimeStamp="2020-08-05T21:57:23Z" 
Target="Production" 
Version="1.0" 
TransactionIdentifier="PLAN_A" 
SequenceNmbr="123456"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PlanCode PlanCodeCode="CHOICE">
        <S_DAYS FARE="10" Start="2020-08-07" End="2020-10-30" Mon="true" Tue="true" Weds="true" Thur="true" Fri="true" Sat="true" Sun="true">
            <STUDENT>
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="1" />
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="2" />
            </STUDENT>
        </S_DAYS>
        <S_DAYS FARE="20" Start="2020-08-07" End="2020-10-30" Mon="true" Tue="true" Weds="true" Thur="true" Fri="true" Sat="true" Sun="true">
            <STUDENT>
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="1" />
                <DIVISION ORIGINAL="150.05" Code="Flat" S_CODE="2" />
            </STUDENT>
        </S_DAYS>
    </PlanCode>
</SSO_XML>') 
 from dual
 )

select h.PlanCodeCode
,b.Original
,b.code
,b.s_code
,x.node_level
 from   t
    cross join
    xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             '/SSO_XML'
             passing t.xml
             columns PlanCodeCode varchar2(100)  path './PlanCode/@PlanCodeCode',
                     attributes xmltype path './PlanCode'
            ) h
    cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             'PlanCode/S_DAYS'
             passing h.attributes
             columns 
                    node_level      for ordinality,
                    attributes xmltype path '/S_DAYS'
            ) x
    cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
             'S_DAYS/STUDENT/DIVISION'
             passing x.attributes
             columns 
                    ORIGINAL number path  '@ORIGINAL',
                    Code            varchar2(100) path '@Code',
                    S_CODE  number path '@S_CODE'
            ) b;
```